# .change() has a slight lag before firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, lag

heres an example of some code I tried.

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file">
<button id="choosefile">Choose file</button>
<script>
$('#choosefile').click(function(){
    $('#fileupload').click();
});
$('#fileupload').change(function(){
    alert('changed!');
});
```

Theres seems to be at least 1-2 second lag between actually choosing a file and then the alert box pop up. this happens to me each time I 1st come to the page.  but after that it becomes instant.  Same thing happens on Firefox 14.0.1 and Chrome.

each time someone new comes to my page they will have that lag.

Comment: i would not worry, maybe some browsers tend to load the file into memory or something! but let me ask you? there's no lag at the second time .. are you selecting the same file each time? if so maybe it's because it was already "loaded" !

Comment: I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5kmQ8/) and it was working instantly.

Comment: this is what i tried > open chrome in incognito mode then run that [http://jsfiddle.net/5kmQ8/]